# Overwriting all elements of ArrayList through each iteration

Tags: android, arraylist

I am overwriting all of the elements in my ArrayList with the last inserted element. If I insert the array of numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6 into the first element and then insert 7,8,9,10,11,12 into the second element, I end up overwriting the first element with the a values from the second element. I end up with a List containing 7,8,9,10,11,12 for both elements. I have looked at some other answers and from what I gather, this has something to do with references being added instead of the values, but I have tried quite a few things with no success. I only try and post questions after I have exhausted my options. Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Here is the relevant part of my application where I am having issues.

```
private View.OnClickListener submitListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    ArrayList<int[]> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    int[] ticketArray = new int[6];
    int counter = 0;
    int tempCounter = 0;
    PowerballPoolManagerApplication app = new PowerballPoolManagerApplication();

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        for (EditText editText : editTextList) {

            if (!editText.getText().toString().matches("")) {

                int currentNumber = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
                ticketArray[tempCounter] = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
                counter++;
                tempCounter++;

                if (counter > 0 && counter % 6 == 0) {

                    tempArrayList.add(ticketArray);
                    tempCounter = 0;
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the immediate looks of things, you're adding the same array to both elements. If you want the array to be unique you either need to clone it, or build it individually each iteration.

That means creating your `ticketArray` inside the loop checking your edit text values.

Comment: That makes sense, I will give it a try. I guess I was confused because when I checked the values in the debugger, I was getting unique values in ticketArray before I did the add each time.

Comment: Thanks izuruel, the cloning the array before adding it helped. I should have also looked closer at my arraylist in the debugger because I also realized that the memory address for each element was the same.

Comment: @MichaelBrooks Glad that this helped you out!